# web Config asp.net <appSettings> tag is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config, appsettings

I'm working on ASP.NET empty web form. When i added   it says,

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

Why is that?
I Googled it then I found this code:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm gonna write it in `web.config` since there is no keyword as `appSettings`.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

So, add it! The `<appSettings>` node should be a child of `<configuration>` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah i added it inside the <configuration> but it still same